# Selenium -- wait for event

Tags: unit-testing, testing, selenium

I need to create a test case, which will have a facebook login.
So how can I force the test user to login with facebook for the test to continue?

Here is the procedure I want:

1. User clicks on a link,
2. It redirects to facebook login,
3. Check the content of the page.

Comment: Have you tried any code yourself yet?  If so, please post.

Answer (score 0):

use the following approach.
1) find the css selector of the link you want to click on.

```
String cssSelector = ..blablalba..;
```

//now you are able to click on the link you've found

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector)).click();
```

//or using js directly:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\'"+cssSelector+"\');");
        stringBuilder.append("x.click();");
        js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
```

2) to verify the content of the page you can find several web elements on fb page and simply verify that element is present on the page:

```
input.findElements(By.xpath("//xpath")).size() > 0
//or by css selector: 
input.findElements(By.cssSeector("html>...blablabla...")).size() > 0
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("html>...blablabla...")).isDisplayed()
```

or simply wait for the besic elements are present on  fb login page using fluent wait:

```
 public WebElement fluentWait(final By locator){
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

        WebElement foo = wait.until(
new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                        return driver.findElement(locator);
                }
                }
);
                           return  foo;              }     ;
```

hope this helps you)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this method:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("save")));
```

//your web object ID is "save".

OR, you can use a custom method. See a sample method below,

```
 public static boolean waitForElement(By element, int timeOutInSeconds){
    boolean found = false;
    try{
        int counter=1;
        while(counter<timeOutInSeconds){
            if(driver.findElements(element).size()>0){
                found = true;
                break;
            }
            else{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return found;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return found;
    }
}
```